# Reveal image under mouse cursor

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, adobe

I am trying to create a mouseover effect that would reveal an image underneath the initial image. The image underneath has to be revealed as the user moves the mouse over the image and the revealed image needs to stay revealed once the user passed the mouse over it, so in the end, if the user passes the mouse all over the initial image, only the underneath image will show. I am using Adobe Muse. Is there a widget or something that does this?

Comment: please show your efforts and post some code with your attempted solutions in a fiddle o show us a link

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

## HTML

```
<body>   
        <canvas id="back"></canvas>
        <canvas id="front" onmousemove="futo(event);"></canvas>
</body>
```

## CSS

```
#back{
     position: fixed;
     width: 400px;
     height: 300px;
     z-index: -1;
}
#front{
     position: fixed;
     width: 400px;
     height: 300px;
     z-index: 1;
}
```

## Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){ 

    var h = new Image();
    h.src = 'image url';
    var back = document.getElementById('back');
    back.width = 400;
    back.height = 300;
    back.getContext('2d').drawImage(h,0,0,back.width,back.height); 
    var front = document.getElementById('front');
    front.width = 400;
    front.height = 300;
    var ctx = front.getContext('2d');
    var f = new Image();
    f.src= 'image url';
    ctx.drawImage(f,0,0,front.width,front.height); 
};

function futo(event){

    //alert("here");
    event = event || window.event; // IE-ism
    var posX = event.clientX;
    var posY = event.clientY; 
    posX = posX - 10;
    posY = posY - 10;
    var pos = "X: " + posX + " Y: " + posY;
        var back = document.getElementById('back');
    var front = document.getElementById('front');
    var backimage = back.getContext('2d').getImageData(0,0,back.width,back.height);
    var frontimage = front.getContext('2d').getImageData(0,0,front.width,front.height);
    var index = (posY * 4 * front.width) + (posX * 4);
    for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < 30; j++){
            frontimage.data[index] = backimage.data[index];
            frontimage.data[index+1] = backimage.data[index+1];
            frontimage.data[index+2] = backimage.data[index+2];
            frontimage.data[index+3] = backimage.data[index+3];
            index = index + 4;
        }
        index = index + (4 * front.width) - 120;
    }
    front.getContext('2d').putImageData(frontimage,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Did you really read what OP is asking for ? "...he revealed image needs to stay revealed once the user passed the mouse over it..."

Comment: It is still not displaying part of the image, but the full image.

Comment: Many thanks, @Sushovan, for answering my question. However, on mouse over the whole front image disappears. What I want is for the front image to gradually disappear and  reveal the underneath image as the user moves the mouse over the front image. Like painting or erasing rather the front image to reveal the underneath one. Just like scratching a lottery ticket.